# draw 1 cm line on any screen resolution

Tags: javascript, pixel, ppi

I want to draw exact 2cm line in javascript, I have already drawn it by using below calculations.

Screen resolution is `1366 x 768`

LCD diagonal `18.5`

i have calculated ppi also

`ppi = (1366*1366 + 768*768) / 18.5 = 85 ppi`

also 
`pixels per cm = 85 / 2.54 = 33.46 ppcm`

now if i draw a line of `33.46` pixels it will exacly equals to `1 cm`, and if i draw a line `33.46 *2` pixels it will equal to `2cm.`

**Question** : how can I draw exactly 1cm or 2cm line on any other screen who's specs are unknown to me ?

Best Regards .

Comment: Impossible. You don't know the pixel density (or size) of the screen the user is using.

Comment: is media query css3 solution ?

Comment: How would those be a solution? You don't have access to the physical size of the screen.